# Transactions in R2BC for MYSQL using dev.miku

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, spring-webflux, reactor, r2dbc

I was trying to implement simple transaction mechanism just to check how it works in reactive world using dev.miku for Mysql but getting below error

```
Receiver class dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.reactivestreams.Publisher beginTransaction(io.r2dbc.spi.TransactionDefinition)'
```

Code I have written is as below

```
@Autowired
private TransactionalOperator operator;

public Mono<ServerResponse> insertUserData(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(UserAndFamilyRequest.class)
            .flatMap(saveFamilyMembers())
            .as(operator::transactional)  //using transactional operator
            .flatMap(familyMemberEntity -> ServerResponse.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(familyMemberEntity));
}


private Function<UserAndFamilyRequest, Mono<List<FamilyMemberEntity>>> saveFamilyMembers() {
    return userAndFamilyRequest -> {
        User user = userAndFamilyRequest.getUser();
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setName(user.getName());
        userEntity.setAge(user.getAge());
        userEntity.setSeats(user.getSeats());
        userRepo.save(userEntity);
        List<FamilyMember> list = userAndFamilyRequest.getFamilyMemberList();
        var entityList = list.stream().map(familyMember -> {
            FamilyMemberEntity familyMemberEntity = new FamilyMemberEntity();
            familyMemberEntity.setName(familyMember.getName());
            familyMemberEntity.setAge(familyMember.getAge());
            return familyMemberEntity;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return familyRepo.saveAll(entityList).collect(Collectors.toList());
    };
}
```

I have tried annotation the method insertUserData with @Transactional but getting the same error.
Using below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I need to import some other dependency for my purpose, or Am i doing something wrong

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you sort this out?

Comment: Have you created a bean so that the `ReactiveTransactionManager` is available to your application?

Comment: @ErikFinnman No Sir, can you refer me an example or some article, I am using dev.miku https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql

Comment: @nobalG Unsure if that driver supports the SPI from Spring, but here's a good tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring

Comment: our team ran into the issue and we had to move to a different library: com.github.jasync-sql/jasync-r2dbc-mysql

Comment: @shaiksphere what was the issue? Was it related to 'transactional' annotation, Does this work with the new library you are using?

Comment: Replying to nobalG. MySqlConnection class implements Connection interface. Connection class has two beginTransaction methods. However, the implementing class MySqlConnection has only one beginTransaction (one which takes no parameters) method implemented. Not sure how the binary got compiled. When I looked at github code, it seems to be fine. But, the binary downloaded from maven central has one beginTransaction method implementation missing in MySqlConnection class. May be related: https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql/issues/250

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your issue is that `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql:0.8.2` does not implement the beginTransaction(TransactionDefinition) method. This version of r2dbc-mysql is quite outdated (3 years old as of now) and is no longer maintained.

I suggest trying either `io.asyncer:r2dbc-mysql:0.9.1` or `io.asyncer:r2dbc-mysql:1.0.0`, depending on your Spring Data version. [io.asyncer:r2dbc-mysql](https://github.com/asyncer-io/r2dbc-mysql) is the official successor to `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql`.